# Bind collection to Treeview in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I'm trying to bind a collection to a treeview. My attempt so far have failed.
I miss something despite the articles I read about the matter.

So far I tried the something like, but the Treeview just plot the Id of class A and thats it, with no button to expand.

```
<Grid>
        <TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="270" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="292" ItemsSource="{Binding ManagerObjects}">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ManagerObject}" ItemsSource="{Binding MyManager}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Manager}" ItemsSource="{Binding ManagerClientServerProperty}">

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ManagerClientServerProperty}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local1:ManagerClientServer}">

                    <TextBlock Text="TEST"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local1:NetworkObject}" ItemsSource="{Binding Entities}">

                    <TextBlock Text="TEST"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local1:RemoteEntity}" ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}">
                    <TextBlock Text="TEST"/>
                    <!-- how classD should look like -->
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>

        </TreeView>

    </Grid>
```

**EDIT: ADDING REAL CODE**

This is in my Model :

```
public class ManagerObject
{
    // PROPERTIES
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public Manager MyManager { get; private set; }
}

public class Manager
    {
    // FIELDS
        private readonly ManagerClientServer managerClientServer;
    // PROPERTIES
        public ManagerClientServer ManagerClientServerProperty { get { return managerClientServer;} }

    /**** OTHER STUFF NON IMPORTANT ****/

    }

public class ManagerClientServer
{
    // FIELDS
    private readonly ObservableCollection<NetworkObject> Clients = new ObservableCollection<NetworkObject>();
    private readonly ObservableCollection<NetworkObject> Servers = new ObservableCollection<NetworkObject>();
    // PROPERTIES
    public ObservableCollection<NetworkObject> ClientsProperty
    {
        get { return Clients; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<NetworkObject> ServersProperty
    {
        get { return Servers; }
    }
     /*** OTHER STUFF NON IMPORTANT HERE ***/
}
public class NetworkObject
{
    // FIELDS
    private readonly ObservableCollection<RemoteEntity> _entities=new ObservableCollection<RemoteEntity>();
    public uint NetworkId { get; private set; }
    // PROPERTIES
    public ObservableCollection<RemoteEntity> Entities
    {
        get { return _entities; }
    }
    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public NetworkObject(uint id)
    {
        NetworkId = id;
    }
}

    public class RemoteEntity
{
    // FIELDS
    private readonly ObservableCollection<int> _fields=new ObservableCollection<int>();
    // PROPERTIES

    public bool IsLost { get; set; }
    public bool NeedUpdate { get; set; }
    public uint SessionId { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<int> Fields
    {
        get { return _fields; }
    }
    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public RemoteEntity(uint id)
    {
        SessionId = id;
    }
}
```

The ViewModel just expose this property:

```
public ObservableCollection<ManagerObject> ManagerObjects
        {
            get { return managerObjects; }

            set
            {
                managerObjects = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(()=>ManagerObjects);
            }
        }
private ObservableCollection<ManagerObject> managerObjects;
```

The initialization is just 2 ManagerObject, after this they all include a random number of NetworkObjects in both Clients and Servers collection and each of those has a random number of Entities.

All collections here are Observable, however, they are of another type in real but they expose a method which can make them Observable so lets consider it this way.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't your ItemsSource be a collection of classes? It would be a parent-child class, and by class I mean your actual entity class. I am guessing your collectionClassA only has an item of 1 with classA in it. Can you show more code, like your model and viewmodel

Comment: collectionclassA is an ObservableCollection<classA> with two items in it.
Its a property of my ViewModel.

Comment: You want to create a ObservableCollection<Class> which includes ClassA,ClassD,ClassE with a child property that is also Observable<Class> which contains their corresponding child.

Comment: Hmm I think thats already done. When you look at my Model: ClassA contains a ref to ClassB which contains a ref to ClassC which contains two lists of classD ...
I'd like to plot the collectionClassA like I see it in the debugger.

Comment: Any thought someone ?

Comment: Seriously I need code to try few things. Can you post more code. The complete project

Comment: Ok I just updated the post. You have everything here

Comment: classA holds a list of classB. is that a private property?

Comment: This classA, classB thing is not helping... your problem is not in this code, it's in your *actual* XAML, so please show that instead... just the relevant bit, of course.

Comment: @devhedgehog classA hold only a ref to classB.

Comment: @Sheridan > I updated the XAML, this is whats in my code.
So far I just see the IDs of the first level and no possibility to expand anything. Note that I Thought that maybe the view start plotting before all elements are initialized but Im doing the allocation to the viewModel private field after initialization and my ViewModel implement the NotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Please *decode* your 'A's, 'B's, 'C's, etc. from your first code class example too.

Comment: You are setting ItemsSource to a simple object reference and not to a list reference. How is that ever gonna work???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I see your problem now and it's a really simple one. You can't expand anything because there is nothing to expand. Your `TreeView.ItemsSource` is bound to the `ManagerObjects` collection and that's ok, because *it is a collection*. However, in your `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for your `ManagerObject` data type, you have this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ManagerObject}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyManager}"> <!-- Look here -->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

You are trying to data bind the `MyManager` property to the `HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource` property, but you can't because *it is not a collection*. Instead, try this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ManagerObject}"> 
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding MyManager}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

You'll have other problems like this too, so you'll have to adjust a number of your templates. For example, this won't work because the `ManagerClientServerProperty` property *is not a collection*:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Manager}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ManagerClientServerProperty}">
    ...
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

You *could* do this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Manager}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ManagerClientServerProperty.Clients}">
    ...
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

... but then that would only be one of the collections. When writing WPF, I've learned that it's *always* best to make your data the right shape to fit your UI. Usually, that just means adding a few extra properties here and there to make your job displaying it easier. For example, instead of using a `CompositeCollection` in the UI, you could just add an extra property to your `ManagerClientServer` class. Maybe something like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<NetworkObject> NetworkObjects
{
    get
    {
        hhh networkObjects = new ObservableCollection<NetworkObject>(Clients);
        networkObjects.Add(Servers);
        return networkObjects;
    }
}
```

Then you could do this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Manager}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ManagerClientServerProperty.NetworkObjects}">
    ...
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Anyway, I guess you get the picture now, so I trust that you can finish the rest on your own. Oh, one last thing... don't be surprised if it won't work, because your data is not in the correct 'shape' that a `TreeView` expects. It *might* work, but if not, forget the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`s and just define `ListBox`es in `DataTemplate`s to bind to the inner collections.

Comment: Ok, we're closer, with your solution I can see the elements from classB, but not in an expand/collapse way, its like the ContentControl just map another stackpanel in the stackpanel. So What I see is classB just below classA but I cant make it appear/disappear

Comment: Ok Thank you very much , its appreciated. I understand the concept of listbox for the collection but why cant I have collapse/expand for the first relations ?

Comment: It's simple... you can't because it is *not a collection*. You *could* start the `TreeView` lower in the hierarchy where the data *is* the correct shape. If you had a collection of `ManagerClientServer` objects then that would work from there down because each class has a collection property for the next level of the hierarchy.